# mongoose setting schema index throws exception after version update, Property 'key' is missing but required in type 'IndexSpecification'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I used to set a schema index using this syntax:

```
mySchema.index({ name: 'text' });
```

So `name` is a property of my schema.

After mongoose update, I'm getting the error below:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IndexSpecification'.
  Property 'key' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'IndexSpecification'.ts(2345)
```

What key should I set here?

mongoose versions:

```
mongoose@^5.13.6

@types/mongoose@^5.11.97
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following mongodb documentation,

key:

> Specifies the index’s fields. For each field, specify a key-value pair
> in which the key is the name of the field to index and the value is
> either the index direction or index type. If specifying direction,
> specify 1 for ascending or -1 for descending.

So the answer would be:

`mySchema.index({ key: { name: 1 }, name: 'nameIndex' });`

Comment: it should be `mySchema.index({ key: { name: 'text }, name: 'nameIndex' });`, because OP wanted to create a text index